# Query multiple tables with manytomany relationship and also check against a timestamp that is in the through table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here's a simplified version of my model class:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content         = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'profile')
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    following       = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'followed_by', blank=True, through='FollowingRelation')
```

```
class FollowingRelation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'd like to query all rows from BlogPost that have been created by the session user, plus all other posts created by the users that the sessionUser is following, but has a timestamp greater than or equal to the timestamp when the session user started following.

I am able to get posts created by the session user and the posts of the users that the session user is following:

```
profiles_exist = user.followed_by.exists
followed_users_id =[]
if profiles_exist:
    followed_users_id = user.profile.following.values_list("profile__user_id",flat=True)
    return self.filter( 
            Q(user=user) |
            Q(user__id__in=followed_users_id)
            ).distinct().order_by("-timestamp")
```

But I am unable to further filter the following users' posts by the timestamp since when they have started being followed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the query without using the ManyToManyThrough relation, perhaps approach it more like a reverse foreign key relation.

```
user.profile.followingrelation_set
.filter(Q(user__id__in=followed_users_id))
.filter(timestamp__gt=THE_TIME_VAR).distinct().order_by("-timestamp")
```